# How to display posts related to selected navigation in wordpress

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-theming

**I am creating a template**

I have navigation menu as - menu1 , menu2 , menu3
I made the categories with same name - menu1, menu2, menu3 .

I want to show all the post of menu1(category) , when user will select menu1 from navigation bar . 
Please specify the logic to do this using wordpress API.

Answer (score 0):

Wordpress does this right out of the box, no extra code required. Depending on your permalink setup, you could link your menu item to something like:

```
http://yoursite.com/category/menu1/
```

I would check on your permalink structure, and then go to your Admin dashboard, go to the Categories you have created and click "View" under one of the categories. This will take you to the page you should link the menu items to.